# Entry field not available for recovery?

Tags: php, ldap

I'm working with LDAP and for some odd reason I am able to recover all entries via PHP but I am not able to get *telephonenumber*. It acts as it if was empty but clearly isn't.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$ds = ldap_connect($LDAP_SERVER);

$sr = ldap_search($ds, $LDAP_PEOPLE, "(|(cn=*$search*)(sn=*$search*)(gn=*$search*)(uid=*$search*)(mail=*$search*))", array('uid', 'sn', 'givenname', 'mail', 'telephoneNumber', 'o') );

ldap_sort($ds, $sr, $_GET['tri']);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if (! isset($entry['uid'])) continue;

    $uid = $entry['uid'][0];
    $telnum = $entry['telephoneNumber'][0];
    if (! isset($entry['telephonenumber'])) continue; //THIS IS EVALUATED AS TRUE
...
}
```

Forgive me if the error is obvious somehow. I've already worked on this a few hours but I'm new to LDAP and what works for other fields does not seem to be working for *telephonenumber*. I am aware there are other entries on LDAP+telephone but I didn't find one that seemed to suit my question properly.

---

EDIT:

I found that the LDAP manager didn't allow access to certain fields, including *telephonenumber*. I am not responsible for authorizations. I sent a request to the sysadmin in order to change authorizations. I think it should fix the problem. I will keep you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between an array item being set and an array item having a value.

For example:

```
$array['test'] = "";
if (!isset($array['test'])) //false
if (empty($array['test'])) //true
```

I imagine your LDAP server always returns a telephone number, regardless of whether there is a value.

You could use

```
if (empty($entry['telephonenumber'])) continue;
```

Instead?

Try `var_dump($entry['telephonenumber'])` and view the output to see what that `$entry` is set to

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt reply Pez. It is much appreciated. Indeed, I didn't catch that, thanks for the reminder. empty(...) is also evaluated as true.

The var_dump returns NULL.

Comment: Can you confirm `empty($value)` return true, `var_dump($variable) = NULL`, but `isset($variable) = true`? That seems to be a contradiction.

Actually just spotted a possible bug in your code, you should be checking if `$telnum = $entry['telephoneNumber'][0]` is empty not of the array is, because it isn't empty, you just read `[0]` from it.

Comment: I confirm empty as true, var_dump as null. However, there is no contradiction as !isset is true. So isset would be false. Thanks for your help Pez. I think I have found the problem. I'll post it as answer below.